# Add default user settings in related table on register, Laravel

Tags: laravel

When a user registers, how do I save some default user settings in a user_settings table I have table? I have the hasOne and belongsTo relation setup for the 2 models. I tried something like this in the  register controller, but got an error.

```
    protected function create(array $data)
{

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    Return Usersetting::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'user_name' => 'u'.$user->id,
        'profile_name' => $user->name,
        'user_email' => $user->email,
        'user_private account' => 0,
        'user_fans_counter' => 1,
        'new_subscriber_alert' => 1,
        'new_tip_alert' => 1,
        'new_private_message_alert' => 1,
        'new_referral_alert' => 1,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: SQL 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip the second part out and add a `registered` method in your `RegisterController`.  If you have the relationships setup correctly then you can add like below

```
public function registered(Request $request, $user) 
{
    $user->userSetting()->create([
        'user_name' => 'u'.$user->id,
        'profile_name' => $user->name,
        'user_email' => $user->email,
        'user_private account' => 0,
        'user_fans_counter' => 1,
        'new_subscriber_alert' => 1,
        'new_tip_alert' => 1,
        'new_private_message_alert' => 1,
        'new_referral_alert' => 1,
    ]);
}
```

This way the `user_id` should automatically be populated through the relationship.

Comment: I won't have to call the method?

Comment: no it automatically calls when registration complete

Comment: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::registered() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate got this error

Comment: Just noticed I put RegistrationController when it should be RegisterController

Comment: You will need to include 'use Illuminate\Http\Request;' in your declarations at the top

Comment: That works!! Getting missing default values for fields i purposely left out. I guess I should make them nullable or something?

Comment: Yeah or add default values